# ¿Palabra adecuada para referirse a un retiro anticipado?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Estoy programando una aplicación móvil y en cierta parte debemos señalar que un empleado se retiró anticipadamente, es decir, se fue del trabajo antes de lo que indicaba su turno. El problema es su longitud, que ocupa mucho espacio en las vistas de la aplicación.

El problema es que no conocemos una palabra que describa esta situación (como "Atraso", en caso de que llegue más tarde de lo que indica su turno) ni se nos ha ocurrido una frase más corta.

¿Hay alguna palabra que se considere adecuada o alguna frase equivalente, más corta?

Comment: Me imagino que ya lo has pensado: "_Ret. Ant_.". No le veo problema.

Comment: La idea es evitar abreviaciones pues hacen que el usuario deba adivinar a que se refieren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Se retiró antes? 
Podrías jugar un poco con la frase o la oración para hacerla más corta. En vez de *anticipadamente* puedes utilizar *antes*. Además si el contexto indica que fue antes de la hora de su turno, se entenderá bien.

Comment: Al equipo le agrado más esta. Me molesta un poco porque estoy seguro que estuvo entre nuestros primeros candidatos pero la descartamos porque queríamos que fuese parecida a un sustantivo. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 4):

Llego tarde, y sé que la pregunta se ha dado ya por contestada, pero quisiera aportar alguna opción más. Si no se usa, espero que por lo menos sirva para que a alguien se le ocurra algo más adecuado que cualquier opción que incluya «retiro», puesto que personalmente me parece que se presta muchísimo a confusión (por «jubilación»).

*John Smith: Se ausenta. 15:04

John Smith: Abandono. 15:04

John Smith: Dejación. 15:04*

Las dos últimas tienen connotación negativa. «Ausente», «ausencia» o «absentismo» me hacen pensar en que el trabajador no llegó a presentarse a su puesto, por lo que he preferido usar la forma pronominal que además de estar más abierta a interpretarse como una partida, es más neutra de connotaciones.

Answer (score 3):

Yo utilizaría **salida temprana**, aunque sólo sea 2 caracteres más corta que tu frase original.

Answer (score 3):

Al leer `retiro anticipado` he pensado que el empleado se **jubilaba** anticipadamente. [`Retiro` en español](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=VJKQUBfgTDXX222oCvtc) tiene más connotación de

> Recogimiento, apartamiento y abstracción.

o de alcanzar la edad (o condición) de jubilación que de salida del trabajo. Un [retirado](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=uZQp72IicDXX2X36HOaf) es alguien que "alcanza la situación de retiro". Esto es, deja de trabajar (no por el día, sino por razón de edad o similar).

La primera opción que a mi se me ocurre sería `incompleto`, pero esto tampoco funciona del todo bien, porque el turno puede quedar incompleto también si el trabajador entra tarde o se toma más tiempo del necesario para almorzar o se ausenta durante el trabajo.

La segunda opción sería usar `inacabado`. Tampoco me parece ideal, pero dado que quieres economizar en espacio/caracteres y estás usando `atraso` para "llega tarde" creo que sería razonable usar `inacabado` para indicar "sale temprano: deja el turno *inacabado*".

También puede ser que el turno no quede *incompleto* si por ejemplo el trabajador entra una hora antes y se marcha una hora antes también (no sé cómo de flexible es la aplicación o la lógica de negocio). Una tercera opción podría ser usar un simple antónimo de "atraso" como es "adelanto". Puede significar "adelanto en la hora de salida", pero no sé si esto interfiere con otros casos de la aplicación, como que el empleado entre antes. Eso ya sería consideración tuya.

Resumiendo, mis propuestas serían (no necesariamente en orden de mejor a peor):

- incompleto
- inacabado
- adelanto

Comment: El otro problema de incompleto e inacabado es que se puede referir a una Jornada Abierta (y que en un momento, internamente, llamamos Incompleta) que corresponde a cuando el empleado no marca su entrada o su salida

Comment: Valdría "adelanto" o "adelantado" entonces? Ten en cuanta que dependiendo de la lógica de la aplicación hay muchos términos que no se pueden aplicar o serían confusos o ambiguos. Por ejemplo "temprano" indica que entró temprano o que salió temprano? Quizá al final tendrás que usar uno de estos y enseñar al usuario a manejar correctamente la aplicación.

Comment: Hasta leer los detalles de la pregunta yo también pensé que se referían a una jubilación anticipada. Me sorprende que la elección haya recaído sobre "retiro", porque se presta muchísimo a confusión.

Comment: Es un asunto de contexto también. La aplicación es para monitorear la asistencia de los empleados todos los días y en realidad no hay gente que se jubile más de una vez ni hay empleados que se jubilen de un momento a otro. 

De hecho, tomando en consideración nuestros clientes, dudo mucho que alguno de los empleados que monitorea la aplicación se jubile.

Supongo que me faltaron detalles.

Comment: @worm318, no creo que te faltasen detalles. Quizá a nosotros nos choca o no nos parece la elección más "óptima", pero los usuarios son así, y al desarrollar software se dan estas cosas. La aplicación es para ellos, y si es lo que mejor les funciona, así debe quedar . Esto es prácticamente nada comparado con cuando el usuario te pide algo que va completamente en contra de la tecnología o el modelo de negocio que ya está usando ;-P

Answer (score 1):

Yo pondría **"Se retira"**. Me parece que queda implícito que el retiro es anticipado.

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que no es muy usado pero es adecuado para tu situación.

> **retiro precoz**

Es un poco más corto que *retiro anticipado* pero no por mucho. Nosé si sea adecuado a tu situación. Pero pienso que sí deja en claro la idea de que el empleado se retiró antes de tiempo.

El problema es que no hay muchos sinónimos de `anticipar`.

Answer (score -4):

En mi opinión podrías usar el término 'salida anticipada'

Comment: Hola Carlos, Bienvenido a SL&U. Generalmente las respuestas que aceptamos como comunidad son respuestas completas y si posible con referencias. Mira la [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help) si tienes otras dudas.

Comment: Ya están usando "retiro anticipado". El problema no es que refleje mejor o peor al situación, es también la longitud en la pantalla. Es una aplicación para móvil.

Answer (score -4):

Yo usaría el verbo desecharse.

**Deseche** o **Desecha**

Comment: Esta respuesta ganaría mucho si explicases por qué crees que esos términos mantienen el significado de "salida temprana".

Comment: -1 Podrías darnos más contexto o una explicación corta de porqué usarías el verbo desechar?